# search specific string in a value from Json and assign to variable in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, chef-infra

Here is my json file

```
{
  "osNameSpace" : "prod",
  "bucketNames" : [ "RC_osbackup_config_d0007cz_idfdafa3", "IC_osbackup_vman_d0007cz_dasdc3w" ],
  "user" : "RC_osbackup_svc_user_d0007cz_dasf2fd",
  "userOcid" : "rcid1.user.oc1..aaaaaaaazf5e27hbpst2pxarisi5qvkmgotwm5ro4nhjkkjq4mmxengckv2a",
  "group" : "RC_osbackup_svc_grp_d0007cz_asdf24"
}
```

I want to search for a string 'osbackup_config' and assign to 'os_conf' variable. similarly for string 'osbackup_vman' to 'os_vman'

I tried the following, but no luck

```
input_file="/root/testjson_2.json"
r = JSON.parse(File.read(input_file))

r["bucketNames"].find {|r1| r1['dbbackup_rman']=='rman'}['rman_bucket_name']
r["bucketNames"].find {|r1| r1['dbbackup_config']=='config'}['config_bucket_name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not this?

```
r['bucketNames'].find { |v| v.include?'osbackup_config' }
```

or

```
os_conf  = r['bucketNames'].find { |v| v['osbackup_config'] }

osbackup_vman = r['bucketNames'].find { |v| v['osbackup_vman'] }
```

Comment: Mind your spaces. `r['bucketNames'].find { |str| str.include? 'osbackup_config' }` https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#spaces-braces